# Why is code not working? (Quaternary Search Algorithm)

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a first project I wanted to create a Quaternary Search Algorithm, I had several mistakes throughout the making, but I slowly understood and solved everything, until just one last bit: when I start the program it gives me the answer "**Element is found at index None**", when it should say "**Element is at index 2**" since x = 3 in this case. This is my code:

```
#Variables
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
x = 3

#Search
def quaternary_search(y,low,high,x):
    if (high >= low):
        low = 0
        mid1 = (high - low)//4
        mid2 = (high - low)//2
        mid3 = 3 * (high - low)//4

        # = First Quarter
        if (y[mid1] == x):
            return mid1

        # = Second Quarter
        elif (y[mid2] == x):
            return mid2

        # = Third Quarter
        elif (y[mid3] == x):
            return mid3

        # In First Quarter
        elif (y[mid1] > x):
            return quaternary_search(y,low,mid1 -1,x)

        # In Second Quarter
        elif (y[mid2] > x):
            return quaternary_search(y,low,mid2 -1,x)

        # In Third Quarter
        elif (y[mid3] > x):
            return quaternary_search(y,low,mid3 -1,x)


    else:
        return -1

result = quaternary_search(y,0,len(y)-1,x) 
if result != -1:
    print("Element is found at index", str(result))

else:
    print("Element is not found")
```

I after the suggestions that I received I made some changes, but this time code doesn't even give an answer. This is how it is right now:

```
 # = First Quarter
        if (y[mid1] == x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(mid1))

        # = Second Quarter
        if (y[mid2] == x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(mid2))

        # = Third Quarter
        if (y[mid3] == x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(mid3))

        # In First Quarter
        if (y[mid1] > x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(quaternary_search((y,low,mid1,x))))
            
        # In Second Quarter
        if (y[mid2] > x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(quaternary_search((y,low,mid2,x))))
               
        # In Third Quarter
        if (y[mid3] > x):
            return ("Element is at index", str(quaternary_search((y,low,mid3,x))))
        
        if (y[mid1] < x) or (y[mid2] < x) or (y[mid3] < x):
            return ("Element is not found")

        else:
            return "Error"
```

Comment: You probably don't want to subtract `1` from the end of the range but instead `quaternary_search(y,low,mid1,x)`...etc. Also, I don't think you have a case for when `x` is greater than `mid3`.

Comment: All your if and elif statements basically are failing at some point. You need to add an else in case everything fails. Or do what @Mark said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default "return" value is `None`.  You need to handle all instances in your if-elif-elif... tree.
You are falling off the end of the elif tree and that situation is not handled, which means the default `None` is returned.

Take these three lines:

```
    # In Third Quarter
    elif (y[mid3] > x):
        return quaternary_search(y,low,mid3 -1,x)
```

and add a pair of lines after them:

```
    # In Third Quarter
    elif (y[mid3] > x):
        return quaternary_search(y,low,mid3 -1,x)
    if y[mid1] < x or y[mid2] < x or y[mid3] < x:
        return "Oops!"  # just adding this line for debug purposes
```

and you'll see that you're not catching all the conditions.

You can of course adjust that logic as needed...

Also, as a side note, you don't need an if-elif tree when you're doing a `return` in each situation. For example,

```
if a:
    return 1
elif b:
    return 2
elif c:
    return 3
```

could be:

```
if a:
    return 1
if b:
    return 2
if c:
    return 3
```